# Getting null in mapping column in Hibernate bidirectional ManytoOne , OnetoMany

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to create bidirectional OnetoMany, ManytoOne mapping. Below are the entity classes StudentAddress and Student3 class:

Student3 entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student3", schema="cf_2583f365_c3c6_499a_a60d_138e7e7023eb")
public class Student3 {
@Id
@Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int student_id;

@Column(name = "STUDENT_NAME")
private String student_name;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="student_address_id",referencedColumnName="address_id")
/*@JoinColumn(name = "student_address_id")*/
private StudentAddress studentAddress;


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student3 [student_id=" + student_id + ", STUDENT_NAME=" + student_name + "]";
}

public int getStudent_id() {
    return student_id;
}

public void setStudent_id(int student_id) {
    this.student_id = student_id;
}

public String getStudent_name() {
    return student_name;
}

public void setStudent_name(String student_name) {
    this.student_name = student_name;
}

public StudentAddress getStudentAddress() {
    return studentAddress;
}

public void setStudentAddress(StudentAddress studentAddress) {
    this.studentAddress = studentAddress;
}

public Student3() {

}

}
```

Student address entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="StudentAddress", schema="cf_2583f365_c3c6_499a_a60d_138e7e7023eb")
public class StudentAddress {

@Id
@Column(name = "address_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int address_id;

@Column(name = "address_detail")
private String address_detail;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "studentAddress")
private List<Student3> students;



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "StudentAddress [address_id=" + address_id + ", address_detail=" + address_detail + ", students="
            + students + "]";
}

public int getAddress_id() {
    return address_id;
}

public void setAddress_id(int address_id) {
    this.address_id = address_id;
}

public String getAddress_detail() {
    return address_detail;
}

public void setAddress_detail(String address_detail) {
    this.address_detail = address_detail;
}

public List<Student3> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public void setStudents(List<Student3> students) {
    this.students = students;
}


public StudentAddress() {

}

}
```

On saving the data from Student3 object , I am able to save data like this:

[image]

[image]

But when I save data from StudentAddress side, I get a null in the student_address_id column:

[image]

[image]

Code to save data from Student3, studentAddress side:

```
/**************SAVE STUDENT Address Controller*************************/
@RequestMapping(value="/saveStudentAddress", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String savestudentaddress (@RequestBody StudentAddress s1) {

    System.out.println(s1);
    studentaddressRepository.save(s1);
    return "success";
}

/**************SAVE STUDENT3 Controller*************************/
@RequestMapping(value="/saveStudent3", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String savestudent (@RequestBody Student3 s1) {

    System.out.println(s1);
    student3Repository.save(s1);
    return "success";
}
```

Json to save data from Student3 side:

```
{
    "student_id" :123, 
    "student_name": "avijit kumar Mamod",

    "studentAddress":{
                    "address_id" : 123,
                    "address_detail" : "209 - Berlington Street"
                    }           
}
```

Json to save data from StudentAddress side:

```
{
"address_id" : 123,
"address_detail" : "209 - Berlington Street",
"students": [{
            "student_id" :123, 
            "student_name": "avijit kumar Mamod"
           }]
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code how you are saving data from StudentAddress side?

Comment: @Abhi I have updated my qn , added codes for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your saveStudentAddress code like below and try

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveStudentAddress", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String savestudentaddress (@RequestBody StudentAddress s1) {
    System.out.println(s1);

    for(Student s: s1.getStudents()){
      s.setAddress(s1);
    }

    studentaddressRepository.save(s1);
    return "success";
}
```

Comment: Its working !! But I dont understand , we are not even saving 's', we are still saving 's1'. Why setting up s, wud make such a difference ??

Comment: That is how Hibernate docs, in this case, suggest saving an object. Hope it helped.

Comment: please see my answer below, this is even more bizzare

Answer (score 1):

Now today, on removing `mappedBy` from `StudentAddress` side & putting `@JoinColumn(name="student_address_id")`, when I tried to save from `studentAddress` side, it did added value in DB `student_address_id`.

`studentAddress` looks like this now:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL/*,mappedBy = "studentAddress"*/)
@JoinColumn(name="student_address_id")
private List<Student3> students;
```

I am not sure why this happened. I dont have extra code as suggested by abhi in above answer. Controller is very simple now:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveStudentAddress", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String savestudentaddress (@RequestBody StudentAddress s1) {
    System.out.println(s1);
   studentaddressRepository.save(s1);
    return "success";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Write OneToMany in both the classes.

Comment: I have edited my question, by mistake I have added StudentAddress Class two times. Now Student3 class is available.